# Nginx deny folder, allow subfolder

Tags: regex, nginx, configuration, url-rewriting, server

In nginx I want to deny access to specific dirs, excluding a specific subdir. It's about the following setup

**Deny access to:**
../css/source/...
../css/min/...
../js/source/...
../js/min/...

**Allow access to:**
../css/min/include...
../js/min/include...

For this setup, I use the following (working) configuration:

```
location /assets/themes/default/css/min/include/ {
    allow all;
}

location /assets/themes/default/js/min/include/ {
    allow all;
}

location /assets/themes/default/css/min/ {
    deny all;
}

location /assets/themes/default/js/min/ {
    deny all;
}


location /assets/themes/default/css/source/ {
    deny all;
}

location /assets/themes/default/js/source/ {
    deny all;
}
```

Thing is, I can imagine that there's an alternative less-code solution. For example with regex rewrites. Any idea how to improve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not nginx fluent, but if you write nothing about a location, what is the default behaviour?

Comment: Why such specific deny? Could you just deny access to /assets/?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte In your nginx config, you need to define a location to make files accessible, and can also use location to limit access to specific dirs (that's what I'm doing here).

Comment: @AlexeyTen In that my css & js files outside the source & min dirs wouldn't be accessible. :)

Comment: @All: Why was this post voted down? I'm really looking for advice how to improve this piece of code. Nothing wrong with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expressions :

```
location ~ /assets/themes/default/(css|js)/(min|source)(?!/include) {
    deny all;
}
```

Your `allow all;` statements and surrounding location blocks are no more useful after this.

Comment: Great, almost there. With this solution the min/include dir is also not accessible. In the min dir, access to everything should be denied, except access toe the min/include dir. Already found this AND clausule for regex (?=!min/include)(?=(min|source)), but this is not working. Any idea?

Comment: @Robin Oops yeah, forgot about this one. Operator `?=` is positive look ahead but as we want to capture URIs to deny, we want to inverse the match so it can be done with negative lookahead (`?!` operator), check the answer update :)